# Textbook on Food Additives?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, chemical-biology

**My Question**. Is there a comprehensive textbook on (synthetic) food additives?

Many textbooks on nutrition omits any discussion of food additives, so I was hoping there is a book devoted to the subject. In particular, I would like to learn about the following:

- How the additives interacts with the human physiology.
- (Lower priority:) how the food additives are synthesized.

Comment: I would say near any additive or small group of them would need an extra chapter, as they have near nothing in common but being added to food. And, it does not mean synthetic ones are the bad ones and natural ones the good ones. This criterium goes across both. Switching to poison topic, many of the most devious poisons are of natural origin.

Comment: @poutnik Is there a reasonable classification of additives then, other than natural vs synthetic?

Comment: Surely there is, their purpose, reflected by their numeric grouping.  See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_number

Comment: This may help to certain extend: Michael Ash and Irene Ash, In *Handbook of Food Additives, Second Edition*; Synapse Information Resources, Inc., 2002, 1079 pages (ISBN-13: 978-1890595364).